# How does mobile application find users nearby

Tags: android

I am working on an android application which can find users nearby. 
I need help in design that application.

I am thinking:
1. When I start my application, I use API to find my location.
2. I send that location to my server.
3. server returns a list of other users nearby.

My question is how can the server keeps track of a list of users who are nearby?

Do I create a background service on phone who will report users location periodically?
And the server maintains a list of all users' location?

Is that approach feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  If you are able to geocode or retrieve your current location lat/lon coordinates, there might be a library that can help you out.

My first thought was the `Geocoder` (https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) library for ruby, it offers a slick API that allows you to easily find other nearby objects:

```
if obj.geocoded?
  obj.nearbys(30)                      # other objects within 30 miles
  obj.distance_from([40.714,-100.234]) # distance from arbitrary point to object
  obj.bearing_to("Paris, France")      # direction from object to arbitrary point
end
```

There are other options that are easy enough too, if you're using PostgreSQL with PostGIS, you have some utility functions that I'm sure you could use to query 'nearby' users.  (Found an example, "What is the best way to find all objects within a radius of another object?" http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch03.html#id434832)

So the overall workflow would be:

1. Request lat/lon from device API
2. Send lat/lon to server/web service
3. Use library/database to find other users within a specified radius
4. Send list of users back down to device

I suspect the most difficult aspect would probably be keeping the lat/lon of other users up to date, but that's a different problem to solve.

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, you'll definitely want to store all the logged in users' lat/lon inside of some sort of database on the server.  It's a very feasible approach, but you'll have to keep it up to date and be able to determine somehow if the data is stale (if that's important to your application).  Whether you use a background service to keep that information up to date is kind of up to you and the constraints of the problem you're trying to solve.